# Why the need to avoid C-style /*... */ comments in Swift?

Tags: swift, comments

I read in [this](https://google.github.io/swift/) Swift Style Guide, which is apparently based on Apple's own Swift library style:

'Non-documentation comments always use the double-slash format (//), never the C-style block format (/* ... */).'

Why is it important not to use C-style comments for multiple lines?

Comment: Referring to multi-line comments as "C style"  is a bit of a misnomer on their part. Both styles are valid in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a few benefits I see in favour of single line comments (`//`) over multi-line comments (`/* */`, calling these "C-style" doesn't really make sense, because both styles are valid in C) are easier to toggle.

1. Single-line comments are easier to insert/remove, because most IDEs have a shortcut for toggling them. In Xcode, it's <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> by default.
2. Multi-line comments introduce more opportunities of inconsistency. Which of these should be used?

   - This approach is compact, but disturbs the horizontal alignment of A

     ```
     /* A 
     B
     C */
     ```
   - This approach keeps the alignment of elements intact, but wastes vertical space:

     ```
     /*
     A
     B
     C
     */
     ```
   - This approach keeps alignment of elements intact, and doesn't take too much extra vertical space

     ```
     /*
     A
     B
     C */
     ```
   - This is the worst of both worlds, I wouldn't recommend it.

     ```
     /* A
     B
     C
     */
     ```
   - This is just better in every way. Alignment is intact. No extra horizontal space is wasted.

     ```
     // A
     // B
     // C
     ```
3. It's easier to make changes to a commented section with single-line comments. Compare:

   - With single line comments, it's only a single action of removing the leading `//`s in the relevant places
     Before:

     ```
     // A
     // B
     // C
     ```

     After:

     ```
     // A
     // B
     C // Just had to remove the leading "//" here
     ```
   - With multi-line comments, it requires you "cut" the `*/` at the end, and paste it at the new end. Two actions.

     Before:

     ```
     /*
     A
     B
     C
     */
     ```

     After:

     ```
     /*
     A
     B
     */ // 1. had to insert "*/" here
     C // 2. had to remove "*/" from the end
     ```
4. This isn't a problem in Swift, but in C, multi-line comments aren't nestable. Suppose you have a function that contains a multi-line comment within it. But you want to temporarily comment out that function (for whatever reason, just an example). If both comments are multi-line, this wouldn't compile. This code isn't valid:

   ```
   /*        // This "/*" is treated as the start of a comment block
   /*        // This "/*" is commented, thus ignored.
   */        // This "*/" is treated as the end of the comment block
   */        // This "*/" tries to close the comment block, but it's not in a comment block. This is invalid.
   ```

   However, Swift doesn't have this problem. I imagine the parser has an internal "comment block nesting level" that it tracks. Every `/*` increments it, and every `*/` decrements that. The comment block is only closed once the "comment block nesting level" is back down to `0`.

### It's not useless

However, that doesn't mean that multi-line comments don't have their use in Swift. I often use them when I'm playing around with a subexpression of a line. For example, if I have this function call:

```
someFunction(someValue + 1, someOtherParam)
```

I can see how a function behaves without that `+ 1` using a block comment:

```
someFunction(someValue /* + 1 */, someOtherParam)
```

Achieving the same thing using only single line comments would require me to do something like:

```
someFunction(someValue // + 1
        , someOtherParam)
```

or introduce a temporary local variable:

```
let incrementedValue = someValue // + 1
someFunction(incrementedValue, someOtherParam)
```

Neither of which are as nice.

Answer (score 4):

While I do not have a concrete answer for you, I'm inclined to suggest the double slash format(//)

I think the Swift Style Guide said it because they are also using it as a default.

What do I mean by that?, for example if you highlight multiple lines and press (cmd+/) it will comment/uncomment all the highlighted lines.

Note: it will uncomment the highlighted lines only if its in the double slash format(//)